# Android ImageView distorted after portrait => landscape => portrait

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, textview

The images tell it all, i get the second image after changing orientation from portrait to landscape and then again turning back to the initial orientation which is portrait. **When i leave out the TextView, everything is fine**. The text is two lines in portrait and it becomes a single line in landscape orientation. This seems to be corrupting the ImageView.

[image: Good] [image: Bad]

In the fragment code, i am doing:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_luminescence, container, false);
mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.readings_detail);
return view;
```

This is my fragment xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.selcukcihan.android.sensors.PressureFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/readings_detail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/luminescence_circle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/circle" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is circle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient

        android:endColor="@color/dark"
        android:gradientRadius="20dp"
        android:startColor="@color/icons"
        android:type="radial"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </gradient>
    <size
        android:height="100dp"
        android:width="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

Edit: I am calling setText on the TextView when sensor readings change, however the string is just constant for this specific sensor. Now the interesting part, if i do not call setText and leave the text as it is, it renders the circle correctly. I am puzzled with this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Are you then putting the shape into the `RelativeLayout` with the `id` pedometer_container? Maybe try using an `ImageView` and then setting `circle.xml` as the background attribute for that `ImageView`. Then use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`. See if that helps.

Comment: TextVieww and ImageView are residing in a LinearLayout within a Fragment (FrameLayout). If i put it in a RelativeLayout, still the same.